# Help computing integral of quarter contour

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, complex-numbers

For a project I'm working on I need to solve the following integral. Can anyone help me tackle this challenge?

The Integral: 
$$ \beta \int_{\pi}^{\pi/2}  {i k^2 r e^{i \theta} + ikr^2 e^{2i\theta} + ir^3e^{3i\theta} \over  cos({a \over 4} ( k + re^{i\theta}))} d\theta$$

Where $\beta$ , $k$ , $r$ , and $a$ are constants and all positive real numbers.

NOTE: k here actually equals $k_{max} = {2 \pi \over a}$

Also, $i$ is the imaginary variable

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE: initial integral:
$$ \beta \int_0^{2\pi \over a} {k^2 \over cos({ka \over 4})} dk$$

The variable k here is the true variable. Note: in the first integral k = $k_{max}$

Comment: Do you have a reason to think it has a closed form expression?? It's pretty messy...

Comment: Have you tried the substitution using the argument of the denominator ?

Comment: I'm onto something, the substitution $z=re^{i\theta}$ greatly simplifies it

Comment: This looks like you are trying to evaluate a contour integral along a quarter circle.

Comment: @TylerHG : It is sadly really messy... I'm more hoping it has a closed form expression. The ultimate end goal is to take the limit as r goes to 0 (which I'm confident the answer should not be zero for my application).

Comment: @JimmyK4542 That's exactly what I'm trying! Nice eye!

Comment: In that case, you should edit the question to say that you want to compute $\displaystyle\lim_{r \to 0}\int_{C_r}\dfrac{k^2+kz+z^2}{\cos(\frac{a}{4}(k+z))}\,dz$ where $C_r$ is the contour from $-r$ to $ir$ along the circle $|z| = r$, or whatever the original question was. (I might have some details incorrect).

Comment: Also, do we know that $\cos \dfrac{ka}{4} = 0$? If not, then it looks like the integral does tend to $0$ as $r \to 0$.

Comment: This is what I got too @JimmyK4542 for confirmation

Comment: @JimmyK4542 I'll edit the question with the original function for you guys to take a peak - thanks for the help as of yet!

Comment: Are there any restrictions on $a$ other than its positivity? @Caitlin

Comment: The integral $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2\pi/a}\dfrac{k^2}{\cos(\tfrac{ka}{4})}\,dk$ doesn't appear to converge. Are you sure this is the correct integral?

Comment: @TylerHG a is a very small real constant (5e-13 to be exact)

Comment: @JimmyK4542 I'm certain this is the integral - that you know, is there any way to solve this function (with the singularity) through contour integrals?